# Unable to compile class for JSP error tomcat,mysql

Tags: java, mysql, jsp, tomcat, servlets

I'm trying to upload my jsp project to tomcat.

Under picture is structure of my jsp project.

[image]

and when in insert.html's function trying to use insert.jsp, under error evoke.

this code is only insert data to mysql server.

[image]

DBConnection.java :

```
package com.exam;

import java.sql.*;

public class DBConnection {

    public static Connection getCon() throws SQLException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        Connection con = null;
        try{
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            String url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/testdb";
            con=DriverManager.getConnection("url", "root", "kcclab");
            System.out.println("DB 연결 완료");
            con.close();
            return con;
        }
        catch(ClassNotFoundException cnfe){
            System.out.println("연결이 안되네요..."+cnfe.getMessage());
            return null;
        } 

    }

}
```

insert.jsp :

```
<%@page import="java.sql.SQLException" %>
<%@page import="java.sql.PreparedStatement" %>
<%@page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=euc-kr"
pageEncoding="euc-kr" %>
<%@page import="java.sql.Connection" %>
<%@page import="com.exam.DBConnection" %>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=euc-kr">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
<%
    request.setCharacterEncoding("euc-kr");
    String id=request.getParameter("ID");
    String pwd=request.getParameter("pwd");

    Connection con=null;
    PreparedStatement pstmt=null;
    String sql="insert into members vlaues(?,?,sysdate)";
    int n=0;

    try{
        con=DBConnection.getCon();
        pstmt=con.prepareStatement(sql);
        pstmt.setString(1, id);
        pstmt.setString(2, pwd);

        n=pstmt.executeUpdate();
    }
    catch(SQLException se){
        System.out.println(se.getMessage());
    }
    finally{
        try{
            if(pstmt!=null) pstmt.close();
            if(con!=null) con.close();
        }
        catch(SQLException se){
            System.out.println(se.getMessage());
        }
    }
%>
<script type="text/javascript">
    if(<%=n%>>0){
        alert("���������� ȸ�����ԵǾ����ϴ�.");
        location.href="../index.html";
    }
    else{
        alert("ȸ�����Կ� �����߽��ϴ�.");
        history.go(-1);
    }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

insert.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=euc-kr">
<title>Insert title here</title>
<style type="text/css">
    #regbox{width:300px;}
    #regbox label{display:block;    width:100px;    float:left; }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<form method="post" action="insert.jsp">
    <fieldset id="regbox">
        <legend>ȸ������</legend>
        <label for="id">���̵�</label>
        <input type="text" name="id"/><br/>
        <label for="pwd">��й�ȣ</label>
        <input type="password" name="pwd"/><br/>
        <input type="submit" value="����">
        <input type="reset" value="���"/>
    </fieldset>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

How Can I avoid this error?

Comment: Are you sure `com.exam.DBConnection` is in classpath?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per my understanding this may happen when you are trying to import the class which is not present under the class path.
Can you please have a look at on your tomcat **webapps** directory ??
The file  **DBConnection.class** just may not be present under **WEB-INF/classes** folder.